# Is there a way to view uploaded and failed documents in Watson Discovery?

Tags: watson, watson-discovery

I have uploaded few **hundreds of documents**, some **documents have failed to upload.**

I need to know which files are uploaded and while have failed.

Answer (score 0):

Watson Data Crawler as of v1.2.5 will output to its log any conversion notices output when a document is uploaded if you enable the `check_document_status` option in `discovery_service.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to monitor the id of each Document as it's ingested, and query the status of that Document id using this end-point: https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/discovery/api/v1/#get-doc to know if it was successfully ingested and if not, why.

(I am an IBM Watson Employee)

Comment: Hi is there any way to get or generate the document url which is uploaded so that, we can gives the user the download option for that link.?